# What is C-equivalent of reference to a pointer "*&"

Tags: c, pointers, reference

Could someone please let me know the C-equivalent of **reference to a pointer** "*&"?

In other word, if my function is like this in C++:

```
void func(int* p, int*& pr)
{
    p++;
    pr++;
}
```

How would I changed the second argument while converting it in C?

**UPDATE:**
@MikeDeSimone : Please let me know if I understood the translated code properly?
Let me start by initializing variable:

```
int i = 10;
int *p1 = &i;
int **pr= &p1;
```

So,  when you performed (*pr)++ , that is basically equivalent to:

```
(p1)++
```

However, ***I fail to understand how would that look from inside main()?***

**Question 2:** what would I do if I have code snippet like this?

```
void pass_by_reference(int*& p)
{
        //Allocate new memory in p: this change would reflect in main
    p = new int;
}
```

Comment: Same as any time you want reference-like behaviour in C, pass the address.

Answer (score 6):

You use a pointer to a pointer.

```
void func(int* p, int** pr)
{
    p++;
    (*pr)++;
}
```

See, for example, the second parameter to [strtoul](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtoul/), which the function uses to return the point at which parsing stopped.

---

Sorry for the late update...

> Please let me know if I understood the translated code properly? Let me start by initializing variable:

```
int i = 10;
int *p1 = &i;
int **pr= &p1;
```

> So, when you performed (*pr)++ , that is basically equivalent to:

```
(p1)++
```

Yes.

> However, I fail to understand how would that look from inside main()?

I don't understand how `main` comes into this; we were talking about `func`. For this discussion, `main` would be a function like any other. Variables declared within a function only exist during execution of that function.

> Question 2: what would I do if I have code snippet like this?

```
void pass_by_reference(int*& p)
{
        //Allocate new memory in p: this change would reflect in main
    p = new int;
}
```

The thing to remember about references passed into functions is that they are just saying "this parameter is a reference to the parameter passed to the function, and changing it changes the original. It is *not* a local copy like non-reference parameters."

Reviewing references in practice:

- If your function is declared `void func(int foo);` and called with `int k = 0; foo(k);` then a *copy* of `k` is made that `func` sees as `foo`.

  - If `func` changes `foo`, `k` does not change. You will often see functions "trash" their passed-in-by-copy parameters like this.
- If your function is declared `void func(int& foo);` and called with `int k = 0; foo(k);` then a *reference* to `k` is made that `func` sees as `foo`.

  - If `func` changes `foo`, it is actually changing `k`.
  - This is often done to "pass back" more values than just the return value, or when the function needs to persistently modify the object somehow.

Now the thing is that C doesn't have references. But, to be honest, C++ references *are C pointers under the hood.* The difference is that references cannot be NULL, should not be taken as pointing to the start of a C array, and references hide the pointer operations to make it look like you're working on the variable directly.

So every time you see a reference in C++, you need to convert it to a pointer in C. The referred-to type *does not matter;* even if it's a pointer, the reference turns into a pointer itself, so you have a pointer-to-pointer.

So what's a pointer, anyway? Remember that memory is just a big array of bytes, with every byte having an address. A pointer is a variable that contains an address. C and C++ give pointers types so the language can determine what kind of data the pointer is pointing to. Thus an `int` is an integer value, and an `int*` is a pointer to an integer value (as opposed to a pointer to a character, or structure, or whatever).

This means you can do two general things with a pointer: you can operate on the pointer itself, or you can operate on the object the pointer is pointing to. The latter is what happens when you use unary prefix `*` (e.g. `*pr`) or `->` if the pointer points to a structure. (`a->b` is really just shorthand for `(*a).b`.)

Comment: Thanks for answering. 
 
Thanks for answering. I am still very confused about pointer-to-pointer and reference-to-pointer business. Please see the update. 1) Could you please point me to relevant resource so that I can understand properly?

Comment: Understanding C pointers is tricky.  The most efficient way is to get help from a friend who already understands them. Just reading from books often does not do it.  It is a bit like learning to bicycle: theory does not help, but it is easy with a little help from a friend.